# How to atomically add vectors in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

i need for my fragment shader invocations to add vectors to some images atomically because more fragments can access the same texel.

So my question is, what is the best way to do this?

Each fragment should add two vectors, one should have 16 bit components and the other 8 bit components.

I thought about a spinlock, but every single spinlock i tried to use is crashing...

Another option would be to pack the data with `packSnorm2x16/4x8` into 3 `R32UI` textures for `atomicAdd`, the first would contain `xy` of the 16 bit vector, the second would contain `z` of the 16 bit vector and the third texture would contain the whole 8 bit vector(`packSnorm4x8`), but the problem is that the sum will exceed `1.0f`, but `(un)packSnorm` is working with signed normalized values, i don't even know if you can just add packed data and get good results.

Comment: Have you considered other options to avoid atomics, like accumulating the vectors in a later pass or using local group storage with compute shaders? Can you elaborate on what you need this for?

Comment: i'm rendering the scene from the lights point of view and each fragment should add the direction from the light source to the fragment into 3D textures, those textures contain my voxelized scene(for voxel cone tracing), at the moment i'm just storing the direction from the light to the voxel center, but thats not accurate, i should store an average vector of the incoming light directions.

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, each fragment then marches the volume along its ray and adds the ray direction to each voxel it marches through? Or how else do multiple fragments access the same texel?

Comment: No, each fragment adds its light information to one single voxel, but because the shadow map resolution is much bigger then the voxel textures, multiple fragments are falling into the same voxel

Comment: It's like normal shadow mapping, the only difference is, that i'm not rendering the lighting on the normal scene, but use the fragment coordinate(cast to ivec3) as index into the voxel texture and save the light information(direction and intensity)

Comment: Ah, I see. That doesn't seem very performant. Even if you are able to implement this using atomics, a single voxel close enough to the light could be written to by half of the fragments in the shadow map, which completely ruins any parallelism between fragments. Would it be possible to instead just set the light ID or even a single bit to the voxels visible from the light and figure out the intensity and average direction later, per-voxel in a compute shader?

Comment: Well, each light is rendered in a separate pass, similar to shadowmaps, right? If 32 lights are enough, then each light would mark its bit in an uint of each visible texel. You don't need atomics for that, since it's an OR operation and all fragments mark the same bit. After you do that for each light with shadows, the compute shader then processes this bitmask and accumulates all the visible lights. If you need more than 32 lights at a time, simply repeat this process for the next group of lights.

Comment: the problem is that there can be multiple lights and each one is throwing shadows, at the moment i'm using only one light source because of my temporary method, but at the end there should be multiple lights possible. A voxel can be only partly lit by a light source.

i thought about unprojecting the shadowmap in a compute shader and put the data in the voxel textures, but would that be better?

Comment: sorry for my edit. I'm trying to say that it would be as accurate as storing a direction from the fragment center to the light source

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123478/discussion-between-quinchilion-and-famz).

Comment: I'm not sure to exactly understand what you are trying to de here, but if I understand correctly, you are trying to read and write to the same texture, which is not possible in GLSL : https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_:_common_mistakes#Sampling_and_Rendering_to_the_Same_Texture

Comment: i'm reading the shadow map and writing to a 3D texture, so no i'm not reading and writing to the same texture. Btw it is possible to read and write the same texture, you can even read after write with barriers

Comment: Your link says you shouldn't sample a texture and render to it, but i'm not outputing anything at all, i'm just getting the data into the 3D texture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a shader storage buffer which contains an array of floats. As mentioned in the comments i'm trying to store the vectors into 3D textures, the SSB contains one float for each component of the vectors for each texel of the 3D textures, also there's one float which is holding the number of vectors added. This is consuming much memory but it seems like there is no better solution.

I'm atomically adding each component of the vectors to the shader storage buffer, for that i'm using the `NV_shader_atomic_float` extension.
Then, in a compute shader, i'm using the float which holds the vector amount for averaging and writing the results in the actual 3D textures.